# CSS @media query not working as intented

Tags: html, css, media

I've had the last media query not do anything at all, is there something about media queries that i am missing?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1025px) and (min-width: 901px){
  .menu-box{
    margin: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:771px){
  .menu-box{
    margin: 3px 1px 3px 1px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) and (min-width: 700px){
  .menu-box{
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  }
}
/* this one does not work */
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px){
  .box-wrapper{
    left: -20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure you are checking with a resolution below 360px ?
2. Add .box-wrapper { position: absolute; left: -20px }

Comment: open in chrome and in `developer tools` tap `Toggle device toolbar` and choose some small resolution. are its work there?

Answer (score 1):

That's strange. It must work. You can see this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxJwLx). Check these:

1. Is the `.box-wrapper` class name correct? Is it class or Id?
2. Does your `.box-wrapper` class have `position: absolute` or `position: relative`? Because `left` CSS property doesn't work on `position: static`. Also 'static' position is default.

Comment: position:relative, and yes the class is correct. Thanks for the help man.

Answer (score 0):

I had done my media queries in-line, which was incorrect.